# TeX works very slowly

Tags: compiling

LaTeX compiler on my Debian system works very slowly. For example, file including only a few lines of text compiles several minutes. All this time LaTeX does something, but what exactly it does is what I can't figure out. I think it is unnormal.

I have texlive installed on my computer:

```sh
$ tex --version  
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)  
kpathsea version 5.0.0  
Copyright 2009 D.E. Knuth.

$ cat easyfile.tex  
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}  
\begin{document}  
Here is some text.  
\end{document}  

$ latex easyfile.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./easyfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for   english,usenglishmax,dumylang,nohyphenation, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/russianb.ldf
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def)

Package babel Warning: No input encoding specified for Russian language on  input line 136.

)) (./easyfile.aux (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
[1] (./easyfile.aux) )
Output written on easyfile.dvi (1 page, 240 bytes).
Transcript written on easyfile.log.
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It would be really helpful if you had a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so either edit your question with the document (even if very basic! The more basic and still slow the better!).
System specs and output from compiler will also be really helpful :)

Comment: Try fc-cache -r.

Comment: When using Russian for the first time it can happen that the compilation is longer, because the system must generate the metric files for the cyrillic fonts. This wouldn't happen in later compilation, unless a new font must be generated.

Comment: But it happens not only for the first time.

Comment: What happens when it runs without `russian`?

Comment: babel says "Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option russian yet." Even if the line that includes babel package is removed at all.

Comment: How long is it taking?  Run `time latex easyfile.tex` and post the results.

Comment: @SergeyLukashev What I meant was removing the `russian` option to see if it made a difference.

Comment: What is also strange is that command `$xdvi easyfile.dvi` takes as many time as compilation.

Comment: @AndrewStacey `real    2m0.602s
user    1m48.255s
sys     0m12.301s`

Comment: @HenrikHansen No difference

Comment: @SergeyLukashev Wow!  That's *long*.  Can you upload your `.log` file somewhere?  It sounds very like something is regenerating the fonts *every* time - that might explain xdvi as well as that also generates fonts.  But they ought to be cached so maybe something's going wrong with that.  Seeing the log would help a lot.

Comment: @AndrewStacey [http://narod.ru/disk/46792364001.ac3aca84e522fcf2f938691e46757992/easyfile.log.html]

Comment: Could you imagine anything on your setup that prevented certain files to not be stored?

Comment: @HenrikHansen No, what do you mean by "certain"?

Comment: @SergeyLukashev I don't see anything strange in that log (I hope I haven't just signed up for something weird.  I don't read cyrillic!)  Hmm.

Comment: Like, maybe you can't write to the disk, or not to all folders or something... Is there something special with your set up? Like user permissions?

Comment: @HenrikHansen  I think not, is's my computer.

Comment: Yes, but you must have set it up? There are few clues, but it seems like the font files are regenerated at every run. Maybe if we could check if where the fonts are and look for changes to see if they actually change.

Comment: @HenrikHansen Do you now how to check whether the fonts are generated every time I use latex? It looks like this is the case.

Comment: @SergeyLukashev The log file is not sufficient. When you launch `latex easyfile` the terminal should also show information about the font that are generated.

Comment: @egreg I've pasted in question all the text from the terminal.

Comment: @SergeyLukashev That's really strange. What does `kpsewhich -var-value VARTEXFONTS` answers?

Comment: @egreg `/tmp/texfonts`

Answer (score 11):

From your comments it results that `VARTEXFONTS` points to a directory under `/tmp`, so the generated fonts will be removed by the system maintenance routine.

Try adding

```
export VARTEXFONTS ~/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts
```

to your `.bashrc` file. This will create the necessary font files in your home.

Consider also to install TeX Live 2011 http://tug.org/texlive as the Debian version of it is very outdated.

Comment: More explicit Debian instructions at [this page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

Comment: The things are not so clear. As can be seen here [http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/ch2.html#s2.5] , default location for fonts cache is `$HOME/.texmf-var/`. This dir exists and isn't empty on my system. Even if tmp' subdir was used (and if the matter is in fonts cache) it would explain slow compilation only for the firts time the system starts up. This being not the case, this answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @SergeyLukashev Sorry, but I don't think there are other explanations. What happens when you use `pdflatex` rather than `latex`? The `.log` file might be more informative.

Comment: @egreg Nothing is changed. There is `.log` file in the comments above. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: @SergeyLukashev That's a `.log` from `latex`. What's the response from `kpsewhich larm1200.tfm`?

Comment: @egreg `/home/sergey/.texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a/larm1000.tfm`